# Too many arguments for public open fun http()

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/kotlin.html) to implement a authentication system in Kotlin using Spring Boot

The code works nicely until this part:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public fun userDetailsService(): UserDetailsService {
        val users: User.UserBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        val manager = InMemoryUserDetailsManager()
        manager.createUser(users.username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build())
        manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build())
        return manager
```

but in the next part i receive the following error and cant import anything:

```
@Order(1)
    @Bean
    open fun apiFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            securityMatcher("/api/**")
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize(anyRequest, hasRole("ADMIN"))
            }
            httpBasic { }
        }
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    open fun formLoginFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
            }
            formLogin { }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is something necessary besides Spring Security dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add import :

```
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring-security-core version 6.1.5 and also have this problem. You indeed need to add an import, but the import that fixed it for me was the following:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.invoke
```

I found the answer here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13092